# Writing dataframe to excel using pandas is uncorrect

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have `df`

```
day
2016-03-01    [00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401, 00102b98bd9...
2016-03-02    [00102b98bd9e71da3cf23fd1f599408d, 0012ea90a6d...
2016-03-03    [00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401, 00102b98bd9...
```

I want write it to `excel`, but afterwards I get

```
day 
2016-03-01  "['00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401'     '00102b98bd9e71da3cf23fd1f599408d'
 '00108f5c5de701ac4386e717a4d07d5b' ..., 'null' 'test017' 'undefined']"
2016-03-02  "['00102b98bd9e71da3cf23fd1f599408d'  '0012ea90a6deb4eeb2924fb13e844136'
 '0019b08bc9bb8da21f3b8ecc945a67d3' ..., 'test4' 'undefined'
 'xx6da37101dffabe00e5d636c01719b6']"
2016-03-03  "['00051f002f5a0c179d7ce191ca2c6401'     '00102b98bd9e71da3cf23fd1f599408d'
 '0012ea90a6deb4eeb2924fb13e844136' ..., 'test017' 'undefined'
 'xx6da37101dffabe00e5d636c01719b6']"
```

I used `df.to_excel('name.xlsx')`. I don't understand, why it wrote the list in the second column without commas.  I did it earlier and it worked as expected, but now it doesn't.

Comment: What exactly is incorrect and what is the desired output?

Comment: I want that will be `list` and elem should be delimited with `,`, like in `df`

Comment: So does your dataframe have two columns one with a day, the other containing a list?

Comment: I did it earlier and it worked

Comment: yes, one is `day`, second contain a `list`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use:

```
df['ColumnID'] = df['ColumnID'].astype(str)
```

on your column with the list to treat it as a string, which should preserve the commas.

Here is a full working example:

```
# create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'day':[1,2,3],'list':[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]})

# convert list column to string
df['list'] = df['list'].astype(str)

# export excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("out.xlsx", engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="data")
writer.save()
```

Which results in the following excel file:

[image]

Comment: How can I give the name to this column? I do `df = df.set_index('mm_id', drop=True).transpose()
df = df.apply(lambda row: row[row != 0].index.tolist(), axis=1)`

Comment: what is the output of df.columns?